# What is the correct way to do external provider logins in 2021?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

My project uses Azure AD login (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp).

I might have configured it wrong, but this does not work well for Safari, likely because of SameSite cookie issues.

You can google "samesite safari" or "safari infinite loop login" and add asp.net core to it and find lots of resources telling you to fix this by changing your cookie to use SameSite None so Safari can log in.

But here the following is said:

The default MinimumSameSitePolicy value is SameSiteMode.Lax to permit OAuth2 authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0.

This doesn't seem right to me because I currently use secure, http only lax and that doesn't work well in Safari.

I am pulling my hair out over this. What is the right way to do external provider logins in 2021 with cookies?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different cookie scenarios here and standard settings are explained below. Cookies are a lot more complex than they appear at first sight.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

Azure AD will use the following settings for the SSO cookie, used for single sign on across apps:

- HTTP Only
- Secure
- SameSite=None

**WEBSITE BASED APP - TEMP LOGIN COOKIE**

.Net will issue a temp cookie before a login redirect containing a **state** parameter. This may be the one causing you problems - it should have these settings - strict will get dropped:

- HTTP Only
- Secure
- SameSite=lax

The state value in the OAuth response to the browser is then verified against the value in the temp login cookie. Once this is verified, the app issues its own Auth cookie.

**WEBSITE BASED APP - AUTH COOKIE**

Your .Net Web app will issue its own Auth cookie once the OAuth response is processed. Ideally you want to use these settings:

- HTTP Only
- Secure
- SameSite=strict

A few known causes for dropped cookies:

- Using HTTP URLs on a developer PC means you need to set Secure=false in your app
- Using pretend host names such as **example.local** configured in your computer's hosts file - Safari requires an internet suffix such as **.com**.
- Cookies are encrypted and decryption failures are common causes of redirect loops in website based apps - this could be happening when .Net tries to process the temp login cookie.
- If your Auth cookie uses **SameSite=strict** and you then navigate back to your app from an email link the Auth cookie will be dropped, leading to a new OAuth redirect.  This results in some companies downgrading to **SameSite=lax**.

**SINGLE PAGE APPS**

SPAs can use a [Back End for Front End](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/09/spa-back-end-for-front-end) pattern so that secure cookies are only ever needed during Ajax requests.

This means the app is never impacted by navigation issues, since cookies are never needed for web requests - they are only needed for API requests. In this model only data requests needs securing.

The SPA on my [Quick Start Page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) uses this option and works fine in Safari.

Comment: "Using HTTP URLs on a developer PC means you need to set Secure=false in your app" - localhost is considered secure in Firefox and Chrome 89+.