# Safari infinite loop when using SameSiteLax with Microsoft Identity Web Web App with Azure AD login

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-web

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68579769/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-external-provider-logins-in-2021) I asked earlier. Sadly, I still have this issue.

MY problem is as follows:

- Be logged in at Microsoft with 2 accounts. For example, go to the Azure portal and log in with 1 account, then sign in with another.
- Go to my application. Select the account you want to log in with, because you can choose 2 different ones. You are immediately logged in.
- Log out. You have to choose the account to log out with. Doesn't matter which one.
- You are now in an infinite redirect loop until the MS login screen apologizes that it can't log you in.
- If you now go to my web app, you *are* logged in. So somehow the cookie is being set, just the redirect seems to fail? I can't find anything in the logging about this.

The funny thing here is that the initial login works for any browser. Not being logged in at all, going to my web app, logging in, logging out, and then logging again seems to work. It's just this weird scenario that doesn't work with Safari 14.

When I change my app cookie to SameSite None, it does work. But I am not satisfied with this result. I have other apps that have basically the same auth setup where the app cookie is Lax and the auth cookie like nonce, correlation,etc ... have the default setup and use SameSite None.

I have a BFF project with .NET 5, Angular 11 and the latest and greatest Microsoft Identity Web library. We use an Azure Active Directory login.

My auth code looks like this:

```cs
// Read up on SameSite cookies for more information:
// Copied from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/f8a37e010cacbc48b63e7d8b875b18b9a2c17313/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg/Startup.cs
// https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/SameSite-Cookies
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
    options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
});

// We use these custom cookie, ticket and token settings to avoid them being set as session tokens, which AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication() would do by default.
// With these settings they are valid for 90 days which means that even if you logged out of your account somewhere else, you'd still be logged in here.
// The problem with session cookies is that the app is installable as a PWA and if you were to end your session by closing your browser and/or log out somewhere else, you'd have to log in again constantly.
// This is actually a feature of single sign out, but could also be annoying for the user. 
// TODO: Perhaps we could investigate a while after launch if users would prefer real single sign out, which would mean using session cookies.
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(WellKnownAuthenticationSchemes.CookieName, opt =>
{
    opt.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    opt.Cookie.Name = "cookie_name";

    opt.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    opt.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Environment.IsDevelopment()
        ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
        : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    opt.SlidingExpiration = true;
    opt.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);
});
services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.Events.OnTicketReceived = context =>
    {
        // Mark the authentication properties as persistent, so the cookie expiration settings will be applied
        context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

services.Configure<MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapterOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);
});

if (Configuration.GetValue("Features:UseDistributedCache", false))
{
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DistributedSqlCache");
    services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        options.TableName = "DistributedCache";
        options.SchemaName = "cache";
    });
}

services.AddAuthentication(WellKnownAuthenticationSchemes.CookieName);

services
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration,
        cookieScheme: WellKnownAuthenticationSchemes.CookieName)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Scopes").Split(" "))
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

var dataProtectionBuilder = services.AddDataProtection();

if (Configuration.GetValue("Features:PersistDataProtectionToDisk", false))
{
    dataProtectionBuilder.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration.GetValue<string>("DataProtection:Path")));
}
```

Logout:

```
// Note: The SPA has a <form method="POST" action="/logout"> which activates this.
[HttpPost("/logout")]
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/"
    }, WellKnownAuthenticationSchemes.CookieName, WellKnownAuthenticationSchemes.OpenIdConnect);
}
```

Does anyone know if I can keep using Lax? Or why Lax could work in other apps but not here?

Comment: You can refer to [Safari 14 infinite loop on login page with default samesite lax sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1420)

Comment: Yeah, I made that issue too. ;) Good point!